# incompatible encoding issue with escaping javascript helper

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a RSS reader and I have to check every x time if a new article is arrived. So I create a function for that in javascript who goes to a controller, then a service, back controller and finish with a js.erb view.

My first issue is that I have an encoding problem on the js.erb file.

My second issue is that even when I don't have data I can't stop the function before goes to the view file. The js.erb then I got a error because the data is nil.

My javascript function :

```
var actu = setInterval(myTimer, 20000);

function myTimer() {
  $.ajax({
  url: '/fluxes/actu',
  method: 'GET',
  });
}
```

My controller action:

```
def actu
  @fluxes = Flux.all
  @new_hash_article = Actualisation.new(@fluxes).call
  if @new_hash_article.length >= 1
    @new_hash_article.each do |key, value|
      @flux = key
      @article = value
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My service:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'simple-rss'
require 'open-uri'

class Actualisation

  def initialize(fluxes)
    @fluxes = fluxes
  end

  def call
    new_hash_article = {}

    @fluxes.each do |flux|
      url = flux.Url
      rss = SimpleRSS.parse open(url)
      @array_items = []
      rss.channel.items.each do |item|
        @array_items << item
      end
      @first = @array_items.first
      calculator = 0
      flux.articles.each do |article|
        if article.Publication == @first.pubDate.to_s
          calculator += 1
        else
          calculator += 0
        end
      end
      if calculator == 0
        article = Article.new
        article.Title = @first.title
        article.Description = @first.description
        article.Url = @first.link
        article.Publication = @first.pubDate
        article.Lu = 0
        article.flux_id = flux.id
        article.save
        new_hash_article[flux] = article
      end
    end
    return new_hash_article
  end
end
```

My view actu.js.erb

```
jQuery('#flux<%= @flux.id %>').append('<%= j render 'articles/show', 
article: @article %>');
```

I don't if it's usefull but it's my articles/show:

```
<li id="<%= article.id %>">
  <div class="content">
    <p><%= article.Title %></p>

    <a href="<%= article.Url %>" target="_blank" data="<%= article.id 
     %>">Voir l'article <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
    <div id="switchlu" class="display">
      <% if article.Lu == 0 %>
        <%= link_to "Afficher comme Lu", articles_marklu_path(id: 
         article.id), :remote => true %>
      <% else %>
        <p><i class="fas fa-check"></i>Lu</p>
        <%= link_to "Afficher comme non Lu", articles_markpalu_path(id: 
         article.id), :remote => true %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

The issue : 
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTZBu.png

Thanks for your time, and your help :)

Comment: you can use conditonals on your js.erb file with erb, like `<% if @article.nil? %> ...` to be sure that you have information there. about the encoding, can you add more details?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I had try it but with null but your right in this I have to use nil. One problem solved ;)